# Como passa dados para uma Classe php via ajax sendo que está classe instancia outra?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, classes

Ola pessoal espero que possam me ajuda, estou com esse problema a muito tempo

Eu passo meu dados via Ajax para minha classe mas na URL não sei como faço para alcança-la de uma forma que não de erro

eu tentei da seguinte forma

```
$.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'Classes/Usuario.class.php',
     ajax:'1',
     data:{id:1},
     success: function (data){
          alert(data)
     }
});
```

### Bom, observações caso ajude a me responderem.

É Obviou que vai dar erro kkkk, como disse minha classe Usuario instancia outra, estende outra então não consigo passar meus valores assim.

Outra coisa que pode ajudar, minhas classes são chamadas automaticamente pelo método magico __autoload(). Eu creio que dessa forma exista uma maneira diferente para escrever a URL.

Bom pessoal, por favor nao indiquem outro post, caso nao entendam diga nos comentarios que estarem com vcs até conseguirmos resolver este problema !

Obrigado por estarem me ajudando ! Até..

### Como solicitado estou logo abaixo vem o código do arquivo Usuario.class.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Pedro
 * Date: 19/01/2016
 * Time: 00:43
 */

class Usuario extends BancoPizza
{
    public $Tabela = 'pizzaria';
    public $Campos = array(
        'nome_pizzaria',
        'usuario_pizzaria',
        'senha_pizzaria',
        'rua_pizzaria',
        'numero_pizzaria',
        'bairro_pizzaria',
        'cidade_pizzaria',
        'uf_pizzaria',
        'status_pizzaria'
    );



    /**
     * @param $dados -> Campos da tabela
     * @param $Campos -> A classe ja tem os campos da tabela
     */


    public function verUm($where=null){
        return parent::verUm($this->Tabela, $where);
    }

    public function verTodos($where=null, $ordem=null)
    {
        return parent::verTodos($this->Tabela, $where, $ordem);
    }

    public function excluir($where)
    {
        //Aqui eu queria pegar a Id do item clicado e através do ajax passar essa id, porem preciso saber como especificar o método que esse meu valor vai, correto ?
        return $_POST['id'];
        return parent::excluir($this->Tabela, $where);
    }

    public function editar($campoTabela, $valor, $id)
    {
        parent::editar($this->Tabela, $campoTabela, $valor, $id);
    }
}
```

Comment: A classe não deixa de ser um arquivo logo é so pegar o post e passar os valores para o objeto

Comment: poste o código da sua Usuario.class.php. O código acima deve ir para algum método na classe Usuario correto? Qual?

Comment: @ThomasLima - cara vc disse uma coisa muito improtante, especificar o método que meus valores vão, a cima atualizei o código. Ficou mais claro para me ajudar ?

Comment: @PedroSoares aparentemente seu único problema é falta de informar para qual método você quer enviar seus dados. Você está usando MVC?
O ideal é que você envie seus dados para uma classe controle, ela será responsável por instanciar sua classe usuário e chamar o método correspondente.

Comment: Não mande o post direto para o arquivo da classe!Envie para uma outra página php que inclua as classes necessárias, instancie elas e faça todo o processo necessário.

Comment: @ThomasLima Acho que estou pegando a ideia, você pode me explicar como faço para chamar o método a partir da URL ?

Comment: @PedroErick - Vou tentar isso, mas o Thomas tem razão, preciso chamar o método além de chamar a classe e instancia-la .. mas não sei como faço isso

Answer (score 1):

Parceiro, partindo do pressuposto de que você não está utilizando MVC, sugiro algo assim:

```
$("body").delegate(".btnAcao", function(e){
     e.preventDefault() //Retirando o comportamento padrão

/*
     *Você pode recuperar os valores do seu form utilizando o método .serializeArray()
     */
    var arrayDados = $("#id_do_form").serializeArray();
    arrayDados['funcao'] = 'excluir';


    $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:'Classes/usuario-controller.class.php',
         data: arrayDados,
         success: function (data){
              alert(data)
         }
    });

});
```

Ao invés de chamar diretamente a sua classe Usuário, você envia seus dados para uma outra página que será responsável por fazer essa ligação entre a sua exibição (View) e a sua classe Usuário (Model). Chamei esse novo arquivo de usuario-controller.php.

Note que os valores do meu form foram pegos com o `.serializeArray()`

**usuario-controller.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * adiciona todos os seus includes que você precisa...
 * 
 * Nesse momento você pode recuperar os valores do seu form normalmente.
 * Aqui você também poderá tratar suas variáveis, limpando-as e se certificando de 
 * que os dados que foram inseridos estão corretos
 */
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id');
$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$telefone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefone');

$metodo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'funcao');


//Instancia a classe que precisa
$usuario = new Usuario();

/**
 * A partir desse momento você poderá chamar o método que você deseja.
 * 
 * OBS: Lembrando que o seu retorno para o página anterior virá daqui...
 * 
 * Como exemplo, vamos excluir o registro informado:
 */

echo $usuario->$metodo($id);

//Se tudo ocorrer bem, o seu retorno será true.
```

A lógica é essa, basta adaptar para o que você precisa.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: nao é possivel fazer isso por dentro da minha classe eu tenho funções, e nao sei como faço para a função certa receber o valor passado pelo ajax.. alguma ideia ?

Comment: @PedroSoares o correto é que o arquivo usuario-controller.php receba os dados, crie a instância de Usuario e manipule suas funções. Você pode criar um outro parâmetro no ajax chamado funcao por exemplo, ai lá vc passa o nome do método que deseja chamar. Veja resposta editada. Você até pode fazer isso direto na classe Usuario, mas terá que fazer essa lógica de receber os dados e instanciar a classe fora da definição da classe, ou seja, fora do { ... }

Comment: sim sim, CARA É DISSO QUE EU PRECISO. finalmente, pode me mostrar um exemplo ?